# Transparent window using Direct2D

Tags: mfc, controls, transparent, direct2d

I have an MFC application and I want to use Direct2D to draw my custom controls.

I need my controls to be transparent. I used to trick my controls to be transparents by overwitting OnEraseBkgnd and calling `afxGlobalData.DrawParentBackground`.

With Direct2D I am using a ID2D1HwndRenderTarget and calling `BeginDraw/EndDraw` from OnPaing method. The problem is that this methods clears the whole area in black even without calling any drawing/clearing function.

Is there a way to draw over a transparent image in Direct2D???

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended-up implementing a workaround. I found two solutions:

1. Using Direct2D/GDI interoperatibility: in the OnPaint I got a `CPaintDC` and then I create a `D2D1DCRenderTarget` and bind them. This solution is quite simple but I got a quite poor performance even when performance was not a limitation in my case.
2. I call `afxGlobalData.DrawParentBackground` to CDC im memory so that I got the control background in a CBitmap object. Then I create a D2D1Bitmap from the CBitmap and use it to clear the control's background instead of a call to Clear method of the render target object. This implies more code but the performance is better (at least in my case but I didn't spent to much time profiling - again performance is not a must but I like to do things in the best way whenever I can).

Of cource, still would be better to be able to draw in a transparent CWnd. This workaround has the drawback that you need to place the control completely over the parent window otherwise you will get just part of your control background.
So please, if someone manages to implement this with a D2D1HwndRenderTarget without calling `afxGlobalData.DrawParentBackground` let mw know!